# Why the requirement for custom allocators to be copyconstructible?

Tags: c++, c++11

The C++11 standard (or at least, [this working draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3376.pdf)) requires that classes which implement the `Allocator` concept provide copy constructors.

This made sense back when all allocators had to be stateless, but when state is allowed in an allocator class, providing a copy constructor might not be desirable.  For example, if the allocator implements some kind of slab allocation system or memory pool, where it maintains an internal freelist.  It seems to me that such an allocator should always be *moved*, never copied.  Actually copying it would require allocating new storage and then completely reproducing the internal state of the original allocator, including all free memory blocks, free-lists, etc.  (Or does "copying" an `Allocator` simply imply returning `Allocator()`, i.e. returning a new default-constructed allocator?)

Actually *copying* a state-ful allocator seems to be totally unnecessary because as far as I can see, in practice there's no real common use-case for copy-constructing an allocator.  No `Container` actually copies an allocator - C++11 containers will call `Allocator::select_on_container_copy_construction` within the container copy constructor instead, which usually just returns `Allocator()`.  Then the container will usually just copy element by element from the other container, probably by just calling `Container::insert`.

Of course an optimized container implementation might do something more complex using internal knowledge about the container structure, but still nobody is going to copy-construct `other.get_allocator()` - the Container will just call `other.get_allocator().select_on_container_copy_construction()` to get a default-constructed allocator.

So why do we have the requirement that an Allocator *itself* must be copy-constructible?  Shouldn't move construction be sufficient?

Note: To be clear, this question is *not* a duplicate of [why does allocator in c++ need a copy constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137227/why-does-allocator-in-c-need-a-copy-constructor).  That question is asking specifically about `std::allocator` (which is stateless), whereas I am asking about custom allocators that implement the `Allocator` concept.

Comment: Doesn't the allocator-aware container constructors take their allocators by const ref? Also, `get_allocator()` is defined to return a copy since before C++11, so a move-only one wouldn't work, and changing that may well be a breaking change.

Answer (score 1):

Re the claim

> **”**  No `Container` actually copies an allocator

that may be so (I haven't tested), and `std::string` may be regarded as a non-`Container`, but still:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>       // std::allocator

template< class Type >
struct Alloc
    : std::allocator<Type>
{
    using Base = std::allocator<Type>;

    template< class Other > 
    struct rebind
    { 
        using other = Alloc<Other>;
    };

    Alloc() {}

    Alloc( Alloc<Type> const& other )
        : Base( other )
    { std::clog << "Alloc::<copy>\n"; }

    template<class Other> 
    Alloc( Alloc<Other> const& other )
        : Base( other )
    { std::clog << "Alloc::<generic-copy>\n"; }
};

auto main() -> int
{
    using namespace std;
    basic_string< char, char_traits<char>, Alloc<char> > a = "A", b = "B";
    a = b;
}
```

Output with Visual C++:

```
Alloc::<copy>
Alloc::<copy>
```

With g++ the number of allocator copy operations is higher.

Comment: libc++ does not copy at all. Also, I think you should add move constructors, since the OP claims *"Shouldn't move construction be sufficient?"* -- this does not change the output for neither VS2013 nor libstdc++, IMHO surprisingly.

Answer (score 0):

The standard library Containers typically have constructors that take a reference-to-`const` of an existing allocator object; e.g. `vector` has [since C++20](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector)

```
constexpr explicit vector( const Allocator& alloc ) noexcept;
```

Move construction would not be appropriate semantics because no resources can be removed from `alloc`, as it is `const`. Copy construction is necessary for this purpose because the lifetime of `alloc` is unspecified and `alloc` cannot be used for state-modifying allocations. See also [Why is allocator const in vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19000544/why-is-allocator-const-in-vector).

You can have an Allocator with a reference to an underlying allocating class to avoid copying memory management data, or to share it across multiple Allocators. But you could safely use state in an Allocator to provide per-Container memory as long as you provide an appropriate copy constructor or `select_on_container_copy_construction` member function (which *could* be a call to the default constructor).

Given an Allocator `A`,

```
std::allocator_traits<A>::select_on_container_copy_construction
```

[returns a copy of `A`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits/select_on_container_copy_construction) if `A` does not provide the member function `select_on_container_copy_construction`.